# Randomly italicized words appear in the admin UI

Tags: 7, theming, users

None big deal, but I noticed that various parts of admin UI (e.g. some of the field name headers, admin menu menu items) get randomly italicized by `<em>` tags inserted for unknown reason.

Has anyone bothered to pin that down to some pattern?

Comment: Could you give us some examples?

Comment: What version of Drupal, and what theme are you using for admin?

Comment: D7. Added tag to reflect that. Next time it happens I'm gonne take snapshot of the page and of the markup snippet.